# objective c convert int to unsigned char hex

Tags: objective-c, char, int, hex

I've to convert

`int x = 4` in to `unsigned char y = 0x04`

`int x = 0` in to `unsigned char y = 0x00`

`int x = -4` in to `unsigned char y = 0xFC`

`int x = -8` in to `unsigned char y = 0xF8`

and so on, till -20 to 0xEC.

Does anyone know a smart way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conversion as such; simply cast from `int` to `unsigned char`:

```
int x = -4;
unsigned char y = (unsigned char)x;
```

There is also no *hex* as such; that's just a formatting option to `printf()` or whatever:

```
printf("y=0x%02x", (unsigned)y);
```